# Tap to Top on status bar is not working in iPhone after fixing content height (Works in ipad) in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page in html where i am fixing the content height as fixed

```
<div id='contentId' class='content' data-role='content' style='height:300px'> </div>
```

because of this Tap to Top feature (tap on status bar to scroll listview to top) stopped working, but it works perfectly when i test the same page in iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched a lot on web, no success, 
Finally tried something at iOS end, 
Here was the problem- 
already web view is a scrollview and with in the page i fixed content's height to fixed so that is second scrollview

This is what i did - 
in scrollview delegate method "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" added this line

```
((UIScrollView *)[[self.webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).scrollsToTop = NO;
```

Boom it worked :)

Note : This issue was only with iPhone not with iPad secondly i am using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; as css in body and it works like charm